# CloudFlare R2 Bucket error with reaching media files from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

i trying host media/image files on cloudflare r2 bucket. I tried lots of stuff  but I still can't reach bucket from outsite with nodeJS.

How can i fix this code?

My Final Code:

```js
fetch('https://USER_ID.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/PROJECT_NAME/src/thumbs/BLAHBLAH', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
        'Authorization': 'SECRET_KEY_FOR_API',
        'X-Amz-Ac': 'private',
        'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        'X-Amz-Date': (new Date().toISOString().split(':').join('').split('.')[0] + 'Z').split('-').join(''),
        'X-Amz-Expires': '86400',
        'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
}}).then(res => res.text()).then(buffer => {
            console.log(buffer);
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? What result do you get? Add that information to your question, it will help you get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement proper [SigV4 signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) for your request.

It'll be easiest to use one of the AWS SDKs, like `aws-sdk-js` - take a look at the example documentation for R2: https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/aws-sdk-js-v3/